# Reading null characters into char array for hex conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am writing a program which reads input from a text file and converts it to hexadecimal for later processing.

```
ifstream fin("input.txt"); //open file with ifstream
if(fin.is_open()){ //check if file is open
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){ //int length for how many characters I need
        fin.get(buffer[i]); //write into char array buffer[256]
    }
}
else{
    cout<<"Can't open file";
    exit(0);
}
fin.close();
```

So everything is fine, it opens up nicely and gets exactly as many characters as I need from there, later I use a function to turn that into a hexadecimal string:

```
std::string string_to_hex(const std::string input)
{
    static const char* const lut = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    size_t len = input.length();

    string output;
    output.reserve(2 * len);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned char c = input[i];

        output.push_back(lut[c >> 4]);
        output.push_back(lut[c & 15]); 
    }
    return output;
}
```

which also works fine, it gives me the correct hexadecimal value for the characters that I get.

Now here is the problem: my file contains null characters (hexadecimal "00" characters aka '\0') which I need to read into my program and do a proper conversion so every null character in my array after conversion should look like "00". Every time I
 try to convert null characters in my array they change into spaces (hexadecimal "20"), which ruins my data for processing later. Changing "20" into "00" is also not an option since the file contains real spaces that also need to be properly processed.

This is my first time working with null characters and I am absolutely confused on how to properly process them. All I know is that null characters are used at the end of a string or an array so when I print them out the program would know when to stop.

I do not know how I should do it properly. I tried opening the file differently using `fopen`, I tried copying my input.txt into an array differently. Maybe it copies it properly but the hex conversion doesn't work. Maybe I shouldn't send it as a string for conversion. I don't know. I also noticed that when I tried to copy paste a sample from the file to another file, all the null characters have been replaced by spaces, maybe it has something to do with this?

Comment: Is the data in the file stored as text or raw data? If the latter you can try `fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), SOME_SIZE);` but it's not portable. PS pass your input string by const reference.

Comment: The data is processed by a computer, so no it is not raw data, also tried to fin.read before without results. passing input by const reference also did not do anything sadly, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue? is the text saved as ASCII or UTF8? Knowing that you will need to adjust the code to analyze wide characters

Comment: Notepad++ says the encoding is in UTF8